# CSS menu will not display child categories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, opencart

We've had a custom Jquery menu which has worked well on our OpenCart store. However the deeper child categories will not display. Anything with a category with 2 or more depth will not show.

So we have a 2 deep category at
http://ocart.site/opencart/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_29_59

But you see it will not display in the main menu at 
http://ocart.site/opencart

If I add back in the default parts of the original default menu, it actually makes the breaks the menu. You can see the comparison of old and new menus at
http://ocart.site/defaultmenutoJQ.html

Something is blocking the load of display somewhere, any ideas on what it could be?

Here is all the relevant code at JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mtq5khz0/

```
  <?php if ($categories) { ?>
  <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
          <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
          <ul>
            <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
            <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
            <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I might be missing something as it's late in the work day but looking at the generated source on the page I can't see where you actually store the menu more than 2 levels down in the HTML.The PHP you have only goes through one level of categories and no further HTML is generated.

Comment: Thanks John. When I put the default OC menu code in the actual menu stops working. Details here http://ocart.site/defaultmenutoJQ.html The new menus JQuery code is in the JSFiddle above